# Writing to the registry is not working

Tags: vbscript, registry

I am attempting to change a DWORD entry in the registry from 0 to 1 in a script so I can deploy it across an entire network via GPO. I have tried every option I can think of and I'm unable to get the `RegWrite` command to work. I get no errors, it just doesn't do anything. I included the echo statements I included for testing to see if the script worked or not.

```
Dim objShell, sRegEntry
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sRegEntry = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options\officestartdefaulttab"

If objShell.RegRead(sRegEntry) <> 0 Then 
    WScript.Echo "I was able to read the registry entry."
End If

objShell.RegWrite sRegEntry, 1, "REG_DWORD"

If objShell.RegRead(sRegEntry) <> 1 Then 
    WScript.Echo "I was able to write the registry entry."
Else
    WScript.Echo "I was unable to write the registry entry."
End If

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Have you tried running your script from an elevated command prompt? (i.e. run with Administrative privileges?)

Comment: Yes. I run the script from an elevated command prompt and the behavior is no different. I was looking into ways for a script to prompt to bypass UAC but I was unable to determine a good way to do so.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps because you are using an elevated command prompt, HKCU is actually pointing to the Admin account. For a specific user, perhaps you need to run the script as the intended user unelevated.

Comment: Do you realize that the value you are writting is `1` but later, when reading, you show a failure if the value retrieved is `1`?

Comment: How *exactly* does your code "not do anything"? How did you verify? How did you elevate the prompt? Is your own user member of the administrators group or did you run the prompt as a different administrator account? Please be more specific about your problem description.

Comment: @StephenQuan If CMD was elevated for the user HKCU would not change (but writing there normally wouldn't require elevated privileges in the first place). Only if CMD was run as a different user HKCU would be different.

Comment: I know that it doesn't do anything because I have the attempted registry change in a .reg file. When I import the reg file into my registry, I can see the change updated in regedit. When I run the script attempting to make the same changes, I don't see the change occur in regedit.

Comment: @MC-ND As far as my testing read, No I was not aware, but I corrected and that lead me to notice the code and the tested registry entry where reading and writing to two different places. I have it worked out. Thank you very much!